# Concourse cannot run on macBook M1chip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, concourse, concourse-pipeline

I am trying to run the concourse locally and I am using their documentation posted on :
https://concourse-ci.org/quick-start.html but when I am running the `docker compose up` and start download all resources at the end is showing this line:

`concourse The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested`

[image]

I have made a bit of research and some guys were suggesting that is needed to specify the platform but that didn't worked, so does anybody have an ideea about how to run concourse locally on macbook M1 chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below docker-compose.yml file. this is running in my Mac M1

````
version: '3'

services:
  concourse-db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: concourse
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: concourse_pass
      POSTGRES_USER: concourse_user
      PGDATA: /database

  concourse:
    image: rdclda/concourse:7.5.0
    command: quickstart
    privileged: true
    depends_on: [concourse-db]
    ports: ["8080:8080"]
    environment:
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_HOST: concourse-db
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_USER: concourse_user
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: concourse_pass
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATABASE: concourse
      # replace this with your external IP address
      CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL: http://localhost:8080
      CONCOURSE_ADD_LOCAL_USER: test:test
      CONCOURSE_MAIN_TEAM_LOCAL_USER: test
      # instead of relying on the default "detect"
      CONCOURSE_WORKER_BAGGAGECLAIM_DRIVER: overlay
      CONCOURSE_CLIENT_SECRET: Y29uY291cnNlLXdlYgo=
      CONCOURSE_TSA_CLIENT_SECRET: Y29uY291cnNlLXdvcmtlcgo=
      CONCOURSE_X_FRAME_OPTIONS: allow
      CONCOURSE_CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY: "*"
      CONCOURSE_CLUSTER_NAME: arm64
      CONCOURSE_WORKER_CONTAINERD_DNS_SERVER: "8.8.8.8"
      CONCOURSE_WORKER_RUNTIME: "houdini"
      CONCOURSE_RUNTIME: "houdini"```
````